# Magento Custom Module creation to overwrite a line in a private function

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a custom module as a patch fix to a piece of code in Magento Core. The private function I am looking to work with is

```
 protected function _prepareExport()
```

here is the section of this function I am looking to work with:

```
 foreach ($dataRows as $productId => &$productData) {
            foreach ($productData as $storeId => &$dataRow) {
                if ($defaultStoreId != $storeId) {
                    $dataRow[self::COL_SKU]      = null;
                    $dataRow[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = null;
                    $dataRow[self::COL_TYPE]     = null;
                } else {
                    $dataRow[self::COL_STORE] = null;
                    $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
                }
```

Specifically:

```
 $dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```

Here is my custom module:

```
class Gfore_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product extends 
  Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product
   {

     protected function _prepareExport()
     {
        $dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productData]);
     }


}
```

My question is: Can I simply overwrite that line like this? Or do I need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:-**

Have you used  in your custom module config.xml file?

Your config.xml,  tag should be like this :-

```
<models>
      <importexport>
        <class>Gfore_ImportExport_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>importexport_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </importexport>
       <importexport>
                <rewrite>
                    <export_entity_product>Gfore_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product</export_entity_product>
                </rewrite>
      </importexport>
    </models>
```

2- In Magento 1.9 New Order email not receive.